# Firebase setDoc with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i want to create a document that has every user that signed in. So i'm creating the document as:

```
const submitUser = async (
    name: string | undefined | null,
    userId: string | undefined,
    photo: string | undefined | null
  ) => {
    const snapshot: DocumentData = await getDoc(doc(db, "allUsers", "list"));
    const currentUsers: { name: string; uid: string; photo: string }[] =
      snapshot.data().users;

    if (currentUsers.map((item) => item.uid == auth.currentUser?.uid)) return;
    else {
      await setDoc(doc(db, "allUsers", "list"), {
        users: [...currentUsers, { name, uid: userId, avatar: photo }],
      });
      console.log("success");
    }
  };
```

But if the user exists in the list, then it will just return.
I'm calling the function as:

```
const googleSignIn = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((res) => {
      setIsAuth(true);
      auth.currentUser &&
        submitUser(
          auth.currentUser.displayName,
          auth.currentUser.uid,
          auth.currentUser.photoURL
        );
    });
  };
```

But it's not adding new users to the list. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what this code does do that's different than what you expect.  Also please provide your debugging information. Do all of the variables contain the data you expect?  Is anything happening at all? What are the contents of the document?  We can't see.

Answer (score 2):

you use map to search for current user - `map` will return an array of mapped elements which will always be `truthy`. You can use `.some((item) => item.uid == auth.currentUser?.uid)` method to seach for current user.

Keep in mind that firebase supports a very low TPS (transactions/requests per seconds) so if you have lots of users logging in this approach may not scale well.

Also keeping current users in a map may be more efficient, you can lookup user by key which is more efficient - O(1) vs O(n)

for example you can keep current user in a document like that:

```
{
"userid1" : {...user},
"userid2" : {...user},
...
}
```

in this case to find current user by id you'd have to do just this:

```js
currentUsers[auth.currentUser?.uid]
```

this lookup is faster than searching in array (on low volume it's not perceptible though).
Another benefit of using a map for your use case: you can use firebase's [`update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) method to update information about the current user only, so you don't need to do this:

```
 users: [...currentUsers, { name, uid: userId, avatar: photo }],
```

(approach above is also not safe if `currentUsers` got updated by another client in between calls so you may remove some users with your update.)

you can simplify it to:

```
update(docRef, {
[auth.currentUser?.uid]:{name, uid: userId, avatar: photo}
});
```

note that there is no spread operator anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain me that map idea? Btw, it's working fine with the some method. Thanks